# Upload and Process File ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, readfile

I'm new to ASP.NET and MVC3 and I'm trying to figure out how to upload a file and process its contents and then display the results in a view.

I can successfully upload a file using the following view code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {
id="UploadForm",
enctype = "multipart/form-data"})){
<input type="file" name="file" id="Upload" size="60" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitID" /> }
```

...And the following controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFile file) {
if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) {
var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/REPO"), fileName);
file.SaveAs(path); }
return RedirectToAction("Index"); }
```

What I can't quite figure out is how to proceed after I've uploaded the file:  I want to execute a server-side code to read the file contents and then display the results on the index view.

So this is what I want to do:

1. Redirect to some process (controller action)
2. Pass the file name in a string to the action
3. Read the file using the server-side program to produce an output (this part is already coded in C# and outputs a string from a string input)
4. Pass that string back to the index view controller to display on the page

What do I do?  Please be explicit with an answer, and not assume too much, because as I said, I am relatively new to ASP.NET and MVC (~2 weeks).  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFile file)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/REPO"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);

            string result = DoStuffWithFile(file);

            ViewBag.FileResult = result;

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Then in the view use `@ViewBag.FileResult` to get the string.